# How to execute code string in Python?

Tags: python, execute, execfile

I know there is a question similar to it here but I am having a different problem.

I have some code files in a plugin but the plugin uses internal paths only the software knows, so I am not able to access that path to use it with `execfile`.

But there is an internal python function called `readInternalFile (path)`, where I can use this internal path and it returns the contents of this file as a string.

So I thought then I could use the standard python function `exec`, but as soon as I do that, it complains about the very first line being '\r\n'.

How can I fix this? I print the type of the data `readInternalFile` returns, and it's `str`, so everything should be fine, right?

The code in the file works by itself and has no syntax errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
s1 = readInternalFile(path)
statements = s1.split("\r\n")
for stmt in statements:
    exec(stmt)
```

should work

```
>>> s1 = "a=32\r\nb=a+5\r\nprint b"
>>> statements = s1.split("\r\n")
>>> for stmt in statements:
...    exec(stmt)
...
37
>>>
```

or you can just replace the endlines with ";" like so

```
>>> s1 = "a=32\r\nb=a+5\r\nprint b"
>>> s2 = s1.replace("\r\n",";")
>>> exec(s2)
37
```

I should also mention that typically using exec is a bad idea...

also this will break if you switch your endline encoding....

Comment: Thanks, now it gives unexpected EOL errors. I will tyr to find another way.

Comment: I removed the empty lines at the top of the file along with file header comments like "# //////////////" and now it works. Not sure why it wouldn't work like that. Because when I used execfile as a test outside the plugin, it does with all those.